# Which parts of the electromagnetic spectrum are difficult to image with?

Tags: optics, visible-light, x-rays, infrared-radiation, imaging

Alternately stated question: **What parts of the [electromagnetic spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum) can't be used in traditional imaging techniques, and why not?**

By 'traditional' I specifically mean using a lens (or some 'focusing device') to bend waves and recreate a physical image, which is then recorded by some technology (film, CCD and CMOS arrays, etc.).

---

**Context**:

I'm working on a single pixel lensless imaging technique that's fairly unique, and may be helpful in wavelength regimes where traditional imaging is difficult or impossible. So I'd like to look into potential applications that might be particularly beneficial. So I'm mainly interested in looking at regimes (such as x-ray) where imaging might be difficult, impossible or limited  to other methods.

I've been trying to fill in the gaps as to what can and cant be done, but can't seem to find a simple reference that already has this information pooled together. So, I'm hoping someone else does have such or reference - or can at least recommend regimes that they know are currently difficult or impossible to image in.

---

**Bonus information:**

Technologies available for a given wavelength regime (CCD, CMOS, etc.),
Non-traditional methods available

---

**My work**

I'll update this with what I find

```
Range      Wavelengths    Focusing Element   Detector        Alternative

Radio                     None?                              Radar


Micro                     Mirrors[1]         Superconducting  
                                             bolometers[2]  

IR         800nm-1mm      Mirrors,? [3] 

Optical    390nm-700nm    Curved Mirror      CCD, CMOS
                          Lens
NUV        300 - 400nm    Special UV Lens
                          and Mirrors
EUV        10nm - 124nm   None(?)
X-Ray      ~10pm-~1nm     None(?)                            Projection Radiography

Gamma      <~10pm         None
```

1-[Micrometer imaging](https://www.nist.gov/mml/materials-measurement-science-division/security-technologies-group/millimeter-wave-imaging), 2-[Micrometer detecting](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1335551/), 3-Is imaging possible across the IR spectrum?

Comment: Below 1GHz dielectric lenses are too heavy, bulky and hence are not practical but they are widely used above 2GHz in ships for radar and direction finding. As an alternative to dielectric lenses a somewhat lighter possibility is waveguide (metallic plate) lenses.

Comment: You should read about the imaging optics in astronomical telescopes which function in radio, x-ray, and gamma-ray wavelengths.

Comment: Below 150 nm there are no lenses and multilayer mirrors are used.

Comment: @hyportnex Are the lenses used in radar above 2 GHz used to actually 'image' (like a telescope, etc), or are they used to collect or direct waves?

Comment: A *microwave lens* is just like any other optical lens, works the same way. At microwaves you have the ability of making layered variable index lens, such as the Luneburg lens that would not be practical below 10microns. These are very large and heavy plastic things, but on a naval vessel there is room and can carry the mass. The receiver or transmitter is in the focus of the lens while the beam is collimated in the infinity - a telescope.

Answer (score 0):

For EUV you list "none" under focusing elements. However mirror optics exists for 13.5 nm EUV Lithographie. Imaging tools are being installed at the leading chip manufacturers as we speak.